# Using OrientDB ETL to load file of Edges

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1, orientdb-etl

I am running OrientDB 2.1.2 from the AWS Marketplace AMI. I have already used ETL to load up two sets of vertices. Now I'm trying to load up a file of Edges into OrientDB with ETL and getting: IllegalArgumentException: destination vertex is null.  I've looked at the documentation and some other examples on the net and my ETL config looks correct to me.  I was hoping someone might have an idea.

My two V subclasses are:

> Author  (authorId, authGivenName, authSurname)  and an index on authorId
>
> Abstract (abstractId) with an index on abstractId

My E subclass

> Authored - no properties or indices defined on it

My Edge file

> (authorId, abstractId) - \t separated fields with one header line with those names

My ETL config:

```
{
  "config": { "log":"debug"},
  "source" : { "file": { "path":"/root/poc1_Datasets/authAbstractEdge1.tsv" }},
  "extractor":{ "row":{} },
  "transformers":[
       { "csv":{ "separator": "\t" } },
       { "merge": {
           "joinFieldName": "authorId",
           "lookup":"Author.authorId"
        } },
       { "vertex":{ "class":"Author" } },
       { "edge" : {
           "class": "Authored",
           "joinFieldName": "abstractId",
           "lookup": "Abstract.abstractId",
           "direction": "out"
        }}
  ],
  "loader":{
    "orientdb":{
        "dbURL":"remote:localhost/DataSpine1",
        "dbType":"graph",
        "wal":false,
        "tx":false
   } }
}
```

When I run ETL with this config and file I get:

```
OrientDB etl v.2.1.2 (build @BUILD@) www.orientdb.com
BEGIN ETL PROCESSOR
[file] DEBUG Reading from file /root/poc1_Datasets/authAbstractEdge1.tsv
[0:csv] DEBUG Transformer input: authorId   abstractId
[0:csv] DEBUG parsing=authorId  abstractId
[0:csv] DEBUG Transformer output: null

2016-06-09 12:15:04:088 WARNI Transformer [csv] returned null, skip rest of pipeline execution [OETLPipeline][1:csv] DEBUG Transformer input: 9-s2.0-10039026700    2-s2.0-29144536313
[1:csv] DEBUG parsing=9-s2.0-10039026700    2-s2.0-29144536313
[1:csv] DEBUG document={authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313}
[1:csv] DEBUG Transformer output: {authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313}
[1:merge] DEBUG Transformer input: {authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313}
[1:merge] DEBUG joinValue=9-s2.0-10039026700, lookupResult=Author#12:10046021{authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,authGivenName:M. A.,authSurname:Turovskaya,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313} v2
[1:merge] DEBUG merged record Author#12:10046021{authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,authGivenName:M. A.,authSurname:Turovskaya,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313} v2 with found record={authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313}
[1:merge] DEBUG Transformer output: Author#12:10046021{authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,authGivenName:M. A.,authSurname:Turovskaya,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313} v2
[1:vertex] DEBUG Transformer input: Author#12:10046021{authorId:9-s2.0-10039026700,authGivenName:M. A.,authSurname:Turovskaya,abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313} v2
[1:vertex] DEBUG Transformer output: v(Author)[#12:10046021]
[1:edge] DEBUG Transformer input: v(Author)[#12:10046021]
[1:edge] DEBUG joinCurrentValue=2-s2.0-29144536313, lookupResult=Abstract#13:16626366{abstractId:2-s2.0-29144536313} v1
Error in Pipeline execution: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: destination vertex is null
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: destination vertex is null
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.addEdge(OrientVertex.java:888)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertex.addEdge(OrientVertex.java:832)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.transformer.OEdgeTransformer.createEdge(OEdgeTransformer.java:188)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.transformer.OEdgeTransformer.executeTransform(OEdgeTransformer.java:117)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.transformer.OAbstractTransformer.transform(OAbstractTransformer.java:37)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLPipeline.execute(OETLPipeline.java:114)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.executeSequentially(OETLProcessor.java:487)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.execute(OETLProcessor.java:291)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:161)
ETL process halted: com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessHaltedException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: destination vertex is null
```

As I look at the debug, it appears that the MERGE successfully found the Author vertex and the EDGE found the Abstract Vertex successfully (based on seeing the RIDs in the output).  I'm stumped as to why I'm getting the Exception.  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to see if with the new etl, teleporter, Version 2.2 solves this problem? 
At this [link](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/Teleporter-Home.html) there is description about new etl product.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I am extracting my graph data from raw XML files and don't have a RDBMS in play.

Answer (score 0):

I actually discovered that the ETL loader in OrientDB version 2.2.2 seems to have solved this issue.  (Note: version 2.2.0 still had the same issue)